# Can I leave certain "scars" when healing Lingering Wounds?

Tags: dnd-5e, healing

Using the rules in the DMG for Lingering wounds I see the need for magical healing (or specific spells) to reverse these injuries. These will even remove scars and things of a superficial nature.

When healing a scar, does the healing have to be applied to that scar specifically, or will any magic healing heal scars? Say my character has a defining scar that is part of his "look" (like a eye scar or something) can I choose to not heal that scar, or will it be healed when other lingering injuries are cured?

Obviously I can just talk to my DM and say that I would like to keep my defining scar, but I am curious as to what the book intends on these things.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Given the wording of the Lingering Injuries when referring to healing, it does specify that the healing restores *the* Lingering Injury. As such I would say that the healing only restores injuries sustained using the Lingering Injuries mechanic.

But otherwise, the book just says magical healing so that's all it is intended to be. Anything beyond that is up to the DM.

Should you wish to keep a scar than yes, talk to the DM.

Answer (score 0):

Hit points according to the 5e DnD Basic rules (page 74) are an abstraction of how much endurance and ability to fight a character has rather than actual wounds. So unless there is a specific wound targeted, healing only rejuvenates endurance and is not actually healing wounds as the character doesn't have any wounds. Therefore your character's scar will last until someone specifically comes and targets the scar as the target of healing (plus you can always say that the scar is actually in the shape of a rare rune of permanence forever marking the PC until a runesmith spends the time to drain it of its mystical properties).

Comment: The question specifically references the Lingering Wounds rules in the  DMG.

Comment: @Miniman Maybe I misunderstand the question but he's worried that his characters distinctive scar would be wiped away with just a little healing and therefor making any significance that his Role-Playing has given the scar a little silly if it disappeared after a healing word. hopefully this explains why I provided the answer that I did